# Outlook 2016(?) desktop takes several seconds to complete some basic operations

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Running Outlook Desktop v2103 build 13901.20462 on a Windows 10 Enterprise laptop.

This has occasionally happened before but now it’s pretty much constant: it is very slow performing these operations:

- Marking a message read when I click on it
- Deleting messages
- Archiving messages when I click on the Archive button

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried some common troubleshooting suggestions like this article: [Outlook not responding, stuck at "Processing," stopped working, or freezes](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/outlook-not-responding-stuck-at-processing-stopped-working-or-freezes-5c313d04-64af-4441-82d2-44e5a43eee5a) mentioned? Outlook Safe mode and New Outlook profile are worth a shot.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.